# How can I add table in a "td" generated by primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, css-tables

I am developing a dynamic table with primefaces 6.0 and JSF 2.2. I have a `TreeNode` of name `nodoRoot`. I am using `h:commandLink` in each `element` for add `children`, rendering the `p:treeNode`. Each `element` has the same `list` of `names` and I would like to show this information of the best way.

I have this:

[image]

I would like:

[image]

Also, in the first image you can see (in red) the subtable has a header, I would like remove this.

This is my code:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="pgSystem">
        <p:treeTable id="tablaSystem" class=" validate tablaNormal" style="border:none;" value="#{myBean.nodoRoot}" var="element">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Sistema
            </f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="Nombre">
                <h:outputText value="#{element.nombre}" />
                <h:panelGroup id="agregarParteHija#{element.id}">
                    <h:commandLink action="#{myBean.cargarNuevaParte(element)}">
                        <f:ajax render="anotherForm" execute="agregarParteHija#{element.id}"/>
                        <i class="material-icons small">add</i>
                    </h:commandLink>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Names">
                <p:dataTable value="#{question.names}" var="name">
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{name}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:column>
        </p:treeTable>
        <br/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Learn how to use CSS. Things like margin, padding, display etc...

Comment: Kuketje, thanks, but I search a automathic solution, with primefaces labels because I know its possible to generate this information better.

Comment: _" I know its possible to generate this information better."_ ??? You cannot 'fix' this in PrimeFaces. You need to fix this with css.

Comment: I did it with css: `div.innertable thead { display:none; }` with `<p:dataTable class='innertable'...`

Comment: @Holger: Did that also remove the padding and/or margins?

Comment: @Kukeltje: Yes. In this sample possibly: `div.outertable td.names { padding: 0px; } div.innertable { margin: 0px; }`

Comment: please create this as an answer then.